# Moving Related Blog Posts on magento product page using fishpig

Tags: magento, fishpig

I'm trying to move the "Related Blog Posts" on the product page from the bottom of the page into a different section of the page (tabs).

The theme I'm using allows me to add a tab which pulls a static block to create a custom tab. I'd like to use this as a place to store the "Related Blog Posts". The custom tab has an identifier of "block_product_tab1"

I tried moving the "related Blog Post" by replacing "product.info.additional" in wordpress.xml with other "block_product_tab1" but that didn't work.

I'm not sure how to continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in your custom tab extension you can set a static block for a tab, you can add the following code to your static block, which will generate the related posts block:

```
{{block type="wordpress/post_associated" name="wp.post.related" template="wordpress/post/associated.phtml" title="Related Blog Posts" entity="product" count="5"}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly! Should I also delete the section of code in the wordpress.xml ?

Comment: The best option would be to add <remove name="wordpress_posts_associated" /> to your local.xml file but if you can't do that, just remove the entry from wordpress.xml

Comment: Thanks Ben! Worked great!

Comment: If the above code worked, can you mark this answer as correct, please?